# Clone from github to IntelliJ - edit configurations?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

Everytime I clone a project from Github, I need to "add configurations" - how can I fix this? What should I do when it says that? Don´t know how to. Thank you so much for help!

Comment: Could you please provide more details? What exactly is the *add configurations* you need to do? A screenshot could help.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Run configurations that you need to create after clone, that is expected if your project does not include IDE's config files. Run configurations are stored within the `.idea` directory in the project, so it is recommended to track the folder in git. See [this article](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems)